# How can I animate a TikZ drawing in beamer?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, animate

Regretfully I didn't find a detailed tutorial about how to animate tikz images, I tried to understand the answer's code of this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131886/animating-a-tikz-picture) but no success. So I just want to rotate the following blue stick for +45degress and then -45degress.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{textpos}

\begin{document}
\begin{textblock*}{50mm}(25mm,25mm)
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [fill=cyan] (0,0) rectangle (4,0.4);
\draw [fill=black] (2,0.2) circle (1mm);
%the following lines are not meant to be on the animation
\draw [>=stealth,->] (0,0.45) arc (180:90:10mm);
\node at (0,1.5) {$+45^\circ$};
\draw [>=stealth,->] (0,-0.05) arc (180:270:10mm);
\node at (0,-1.1) {$-45^\circ$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{textblock*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I wrote two tutorials here, have you read them? [How to create simple animations with `animate`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/401886/138900)

Comment: Oh I will check it and see what can I do @AndréC.

Comment: And when you've done the animation, don't forget to answer your own question.

Comment: I see you've accepted a solution. You couldn't make the animation yourself?

Comment: I didn't understand the logic behind some commands so I gave up :( @AndréC

Comment: Say what you didn't understand, I will answer and modify the tutorial to make it clearer.

Comment: Okay I will, I appreciate it @AndréC

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In this case an approach can be done with the [animate](https://ctan.org/pkg/animate?lang=de) package and the `rotate around={<angle>:<coordinate>}` `TikZ`-option. If your goal is a presentation you can used the `beamer` document class and if not you can use other classes.

The [animate](https://ctan.org/pkg/animate?lang=de) package can be invoke with several options, s. pp. 3-4 of the [package documentation](https://ctan.net/macros/latex/contrib/animate/animate.pdf). Of all commands the `\multiframe` one allows loops around pictures, such as `TikZ` pictures. Nevertheless, this command must be surrounded by `\begin{animateinline}` and `\end{animateinline}`environment (or by any of the `\newframe` variants), s. p. 5.

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[options]{animate}
%...
%...
  \begin{animateinline}[options]{...}{...}{...}{...}
    \multiframe{<number of frames>}{[<variables>]}{
       loop body
    }
  \end{animateinline}
```

The environment has also other options, s. pp. 7-10, Chapter 6. Among others:

- `loop`: "The animation restarts immediately after reaching the end."
- `autoplay`: "Start animation after the page has opened."
- `controls`: "Inserts control buttons below the animation widget."
- `palindrome` : "The animation continuously plays forwards and backwards"

The command `\multiframe` has three arguments:

1. `number of frames`: the maximum number of iterations/frames.
2. `variables`: iteration increment in the form:
   `<variable name>=<initial value>+<increment>`
3. `loop body` : code with and/or without variables. Here you can define your `tikzpicture` environment.

**Note**

> "Unlike ‘pspicture’, the ‘tikzpicture’ environment is able to determine its size from the graphical objects it encloses.
> However, this may result in differently sized frames of a sequence, depending on the size and position of the graphical objects. Thus, in order to ensure that all frames of the sequence be displayed at the same scale in the animation widget, a common bounding box should be shared by the frames. A bounding box can be provided by means of an invisible ‘rectangle’ object", s. p.10:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \useasboundingbox (... , ...) rectangle (... , ...);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Or you can add phantom nodes for the same purpose.

Finally, the stick direction can be change with an `if-then` statement by using the [ifthen](https://ctan.org/pkg/ifthen?lang=de) package:

```
\ifthenelse{boolean condition}{then clause}{else clause}
```

A possible solution is given by the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{RGB}{10,90,10}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{animateinline}[controls,loop]{50}
            \multiframe{180}{rt=-45+1}{%
                \begin{tikzpicture}
                \ifthenelse{\rt < 45}
                {\draw[rounded corners,fill=cyan,rotate around={180-\rt:(2,0.2)}] (0,0) rectangle (4,0.4);\draw [fill=white] (2,0.2) circle (1mm);\draw[fill=darkgreen] (2,0.2) circle (0.5mm);}
                {\draw[rounded corners,fill=darkgreen,rotate around={90+\rt:(2,0.2)}] (0,0) rectangle (4,0.4);\draw [fill=white] (2,0.2) circle (1mm);\draw[fill=cyan] (2,0.2) circle (0.5mm);};
%               \draw [fill=black] (2,0.2) circle (1mm);
                %the following lines are not meant to be on the animation
                \draw [>=stealth,->,very thick] ([shift=(175:2.15)]2,0.2) arc (175:135:2.15) node[xshift=-5pt,left] {$+45^\circ$};
                \draw [>=stealth,->,very thick] ([shift=(185:2.15)]2,0.2) arc (185:225:2.15) node[xshift=-5pt,left] {$-45^\circ$};
                \node at (4.0,4.0) {}; %phantom node
                \node at (-4.0,-4.0) {}; %phantom node
                \end{tikzpicture}}%
        \end{animateinline}
    \end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What's the phantom nodes for ? @Ñako

Comment: @ Hibou        the image size changes during the animation, so that the animation "moves" horizontally. With the phantom nodes `(4.5,4.5)` and `(-4.5,-4.5)` the image size is increased and thus this effect is avoided.

Comment: It works perfectly, one last thing, is it possible to stop/hold the animation after after a certain time ? @Ñako

Comment: @ Hibou        Have a look at the edit, please

Comment: It would be much more beautiful, if the arrow indicating the 45° angle and the blue stick did not overlap.

Comment: @AndréC        Well, some things are a matter of taste. Try the edit again, please

Comment: @Ñako It's much more beautiful, but the stick turns black when it reaches 45°!

Comment: @Ñako In addition, it would be good to explain how to make an animation *(that's the question, by the way)*, because Hibou despite my tutorials and despite your answer still doesn't know how to do it.

Comment: @AndréC        I´ve checked the single frames and  have not found the black stick. For 44° is cyan and for 45° is darkgreen.  Did I miss something? Maybe the transition?
Yes, of course, I am going to explain it a little bit

Comment: @Ñako It's possible that it's from the gif conversion. How did you convert it to a gif?

Comment: @AndréC        I haven't thoroughly checked the gif version. I compile the code as `standalone` document class and with the option `export` of the `animate`package. Then I have used the [Online PDF to GIF converter](https://ezgif.com/pdf-to-gif)

Comment: Try with [Imagemagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php)

Answer (score 15):

I didn't think that this answer has more than 3 reputations ...

```
import animate;
import roundedpath;
settings.tex="pdflatex"; 
animation Ani;
unitsize(1cm);
path roundedbox=roundedpath(box((0,0),(4,0.4)),0.15);
path Arc=reverse(arc((2,0.2),2.15,135,175));
draw(Label("$+45^\circ$",Relative(.9),LeftSide),Arc,Arrow);
draw(Label("$-45^\circ$",Relative(.9)),reflect((2,0.2),(2.1,0.2))*Arc,Arrow);
for(int a=0; a<=45;++a)
{
save();
filldraw(rotate(-a,(2,0.2))*roundedbox,cyan);
dot((2,0.2),linewidth(3bp));
Ani.add();
restore();
}
for(int a=44; a >=-45; --a)
{
save();
filldraw(rotate(-a,(2,0.2))*roundedbox,red);
dot((2,0.2),linewidth(3bp));
Ani.add();
restore();
}
for(int a=44; a>0;--a)
{
save();
filldraw(rotate(a,(2,0.2))*roundedbox,blue);
dot((2,0.2),linewidth(3bp));
Ani.add();
restore();
}
erase();
Ani.movie(BBox(Fill(white)));
```

[image]

Only for the compare purpose with [Asymptote](https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/).

```
import animate;
settings.tex="pdflatex"; 
animation Ani;
unitsize(1cm);
for(int a=0; a<=45;++a)
{
save();
filldraw(rotate(-a,(2,0.2))*box((0,0),(4,0.4)),cyan);
dot((2,0.2));
Ani.add();
restore();
}
for(int a=44; a >=-45; --a)
{
save();
filldraw(rotate(-a,(2,0.2))*box((0,0),(4,0.4)),cyan);
dot((2,0.2));
Ani.add();
restore();
}
for(int a=44; a>=0;--a)
{
save();
filldraw(rotate(a,(2,0.2))*box((0,0),(4,0.4)),cyan);
dot((2,0.2));
Ani.add();
restore();
}
erase();
Ani.movie(BBox(Fill(white)));
```

[image]

With PSTricks - *my first tool drawin*g (converts from my Asymptote to PSTricks).

I use https://ezgif.com/pdf-to-gif to convert my PDF to gif!

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\Picture}[2]{
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-1,-2)(5,2)
\psrotate(2,0.2){#1}{\psframe[fillcolor=#2,fillstyle=solid,framearc=0.5](0,0)(4,0.4)}
\psarc{->}(2,0.2){2.15}{185}{225}
\psarcn{->}(2,0.2){2.15}{175}{135}
\psdot(2,0.2)
\rput(0,1.75){$+45^\circ$}
\rput(0,-1.5){$-45^\circ$}
\end{pspicture}%
}
\multido{\i=0+1}{46}{%
  \Picture{-\i}{cyan}
}
\multido{\i=-44+1}{90}{%
\Picture{\i}{red}
}
\multido{\i=44+-1}{44}{%
\Picture{\i}{blue}
}
\end{document}
```

From `PSTricks code above`, I have decided to use Asymptote to replace **it** !!!

[image]