# Text and tikz animation in one slide

Tags: beamer, columns, text, animate, tikz-pic

I found a TikZ animation example [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/558850/how-can-i-animate-a-tikz-drawing-in-beamer).

In the next step I tried to put text beside the animation, doing the following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{RGB}{10,90,10}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            \begin{animateinline}[controls,loop]{50}
                \multiframe{180}{rt=-45+1}{%
                    \begin{tikzpicture}
                    \ifthenelse{\rt < 45}
                    {\draw[rounded corners,fill=cyan,rotate around={180-\rt:(2,0.2)}] (0,0) rectangle (4,0.4);\draw [fill=white] (2,0.2) circle (1mm);\draw[fill=darkgreen] (2,0.2) circle (0.5mm);}
                    {\draw[rounded corners,fill=darkgreen,rotate around={90+\rt:(2,0.2)}] (0,0) rectangle (4,0.4);\draw [fill=white] (2,0.2) circle (1mm);\draw[fill=cyan] (2,0.2) circle (0.5mm);};
        %               \draw [fill=black] (2,0.2) circle (1mm);
                    %the following lines are not meant to be on the animation
                    \draw [>=stealth,->,very thick] ([shift=(175:2.15)]2,0.2) arc (175:135:2.15) node[xshift=-5pt,left] {$+45^\circ$};
                    \draw [>=stealth,->,very thick] ([shift=(185:2.15)]2,0.2) arc (185:225:2.15) node[xshift=-5pt,left] {$-45^\circ$};
                    \node at (4.0,4.0) {}; %phantom node
                    \node at (-4.0,-4.0) {}; %phantom node
                    \end{tikzpicture}}%
            \end{animateinline}
        \end{column}
        \end{columns}
    \end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

How do I have to change the code, that the text is in the first and the animation completeley within the second column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is, the `tikzpicture` is simply too wide to fit into the right column. The phantom nodes add too much white-space around the visible graphic objects.

The animation's vertical extension and the left-hand bounding edge are determined by the text labels "+45°" and "-45°". Only the right bounding edge needs to be fixed, which could indeed be done by means of a phantom node, or another invisible object.

The fixed code might look like this:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{RGB}{10,90,10}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            \begin{animateinline}[controls,loop]{50}
                \multiframe{180}{rt=-45+1}{%
                    \begin{tikzpicture}
                    \ifthenelse{\rt < 45}
                    {\draw[rounded corners,fill=cyan,rotate around={180-\rt:(2,0.2)}] (0,0) rectangle (4,0.4);\draw [fill=white] (2,0.2) circle (1mm);\draw[fill=darkgreen] (2,0.2) circle (0.5mm);}
                    {\draw[rounded corners,fill=darkgreen,rotate around={90+\rt:(2,0.2)}] (0,0) rectangle (4,0.4);\draw [fill=white] (2,0.2) circle (1mm);\draw[fill=cyan] (2,0.2) circle (0.5mm);};
        %               \draw [fill=black] (2,0.2) circle (1mm);
                    %the following lines are not meant to be on the animation
                    \draw [>=stealth,->,very thick] ([shift=(175:2.15)]2,0.2) arc (175:135:2.15) node[xshift=-5pt,left] {$+45^\circ$};
                    \draw [>=stealth,->,very thick] ([shift=(185:2.15)]2,0.2) arc (185:225:2.15) node[xshift=-5pt,left] {$-45^\circ$};
                    \node at (4.0,0) {}; % phantom node to mark right horiz. extension
                    \end{tikzpicture}}%
            \end{animateinline}
        \end{column}
        \end{columns}
    \end{frame} 
\end{document}
```